# HttpHandler path matching

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

In ASP.NET 4.0 with IIS7, I created a HttpHandler and registered it in web.config

```
<add name="MyHandler" path="MyPath/*" verb="*" type="MyProject.MyHandler, MyHandler" />
```

Here, what I try to achieve is to handle all the file requests to `http://my-server/MyPath/*`, but with such settings the requests to `http://my-server/SubFolder/MyPath/*` will also be handled, not what I want.

Is the absolute path the only way I can use to guarantee first level folder match?

Any other better idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use location element for this

```
<location path="MyPath">
  <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
      <add name="MyHandler" path="MyPath/*" verb="*" type="MyProject.MyHandler, MyHandler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Comment: Not working, event requests like `http://my-server/public/home.aspx` is not captured by handler.

Comment: Thats what you want, isn't it? All the file inside the MyPath folder at the root will be handled, nothing else.

Comment: I want to be able to handle `http://my-server/public/*` but not `http://my-server/subfolder/public/*`, but by using location I cannot match `~/MyFolder/*` at all.

Comment: Did you modify the values in the location path to suit your need?

Comment: Gotha, I have to use `<location path="MyPath">` instead of `<location path="~/MyPath">` to work.